# How to delete the video file along with the selected adapter in a listview?

Tags: java, android, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete entry and video file in a listview file browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003439/how-to-delete-entry-and-video-file-in-a-listview-file-browser)

Problem description: I wanted it such that when an adapter is selected in a listview it will delete the appropriate or residing video file in the Video_List directory and at the same time it will remove the particular adapter from the view of the listview..

I'm rather new in android/java can someone help me with it?