# How do i display a custom dialog box from a function?

Tags: android, dialog

In my videolist app, I have 2 options which is details and delete that calls function. Details function is to read some information from a file and then display it in a dialog box. My problem is getting the dialog box to work. Delete function is to simply delete it from the list. I am using [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) as a reference, but the methods they used doesn't work for me. I'm doing something similar like [this](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/travel_and_local/autoguard-blackbox_llix_screenshots.html) in the 3rd picture from the top.

Comment: what the error you are getting ??

Comment: @Sujit I can't display the info in the dialog box and the link above doesn't state anything about displaying info

Comment: @exception i think you should take a look at a link here done by my partner also having  similar problem --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987692/how-to-delete-the-video-file-along-with-the-selected-adapter-in-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

You defined an override onListItemClick but this code is never been called. You should also register the a listener to the view you're using. Check how android handle [user interface events.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
newListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: hi could you answer the specific problem here instead becuase my friend is more active there --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987692/how-to-delete-the-video-file-along-with-the-selected-adapter-in-a-listview